# Green/red widget icon or notification tray app to indicate if internet is available (tablet)

Tags: applications, internet

Consider a tablet user without data plan using only wifi connections at public places (e.g., hospital, hotel) that often die after 2 hours after accepting terms of use.
(and is not running skype or other app all the time to show connected status)

Is there a widget (similar to battery-big text % of battery in the time top system line) that would show green if internet is available to the tablet and red if internet "died" (due to inactivity or other glitch).

Comment: Don't the connection icons in the status bar suffice for that? If they show gray, Google services can't be reached. If they have no bars, there's no coverage. If there's no WiFi icon, there's no WiFi connection active. And if there's no G/E/3G/H/H+/LTE next to the network icon, there are no mobile data available. Should do, I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANdroid default icon provides the functionality

color of the icon (gray) already indicates "sign-in required" type of connection.

(credit goez to izzy)